# Modal with overlaying anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Although I am quickly learning JS I have a problem i can't figure out. I have a modal which is in a `<div>` and a `<div>` that contains an image and product name, when I hover over this `<div>` I get a hover icon which is an `<a>`. When I click on the `<div>` with the image in it a modal pops up - this works brilliantly. But When I click the `<a>` the modal pops up and then you are taken to the link. I don't want the modal to appear when you click the overlaying `<a>`.

Here's my HTML for the Modal:

```
<div class="modal myModal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>
    <div class="popup-image-container">

    <img id="popup-image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame($_imageKeepFrame)->resize($_gridImageSize); ?>" srcset="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame($_imageKeepFrame)->resize($_gridImageSize); ?> 1x, <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame($_imageKeepFrame)->resize($_gridImageSize * 2); ?> 2x"
                            width="75%" height="75%"
                            alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"
                        /></div>
    <div class="popup-buttons ">
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('View Detail') ?>" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('More Detail') ?></span></span></button>

<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Visit Store') ?>" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check"onclick="window.open('<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getAdvertiserBuyLink(), 'advertiser_buy_link') ?>', '_blank');"<span><span><?php echo $this->__('Goto Store') ?></span></span></button></p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

and for the Product

```
            <div class="prolabel-wrapper">
                <?php echo Mage::helper('prolabels')->getLabel($_product, 'category'); ?>
                <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                    src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame($_imageKeepFrame)->resize($_gridImageSize); ?>"
                    srcset="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame($_imageKeepFrame)->resize($_gridImageSize); ?> 1x, <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame($_imageKeepFrame)->resize($_gridImageSize * 2); ?> 2x"
                    width="<?php echo $_gridImageSize ?>" height="<?php echo $_gridImageSize ?>"
                    alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"
                />
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <li class="li-wishlist"><a rel="nofollow" id="wishlist" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" onclick="return false;"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <li class="li-compare"><a rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Here is the JS that I created:

```
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("prolabel-wrapper");

var spans=document.getElementsByClassName("close");

var wishlist=document.getElementsByClassName("link-wishlist");

var showPopup = true;
// Get the modal
window.onload = function(){

for(let i=0;i<wishlist.length;i++) {
   wishlist[i].onclick = function() {
      var showPopup = false;
      alert("Here - showPopup is " + showPopup);
      modals[i].style.display = "none";
      return false;
   }
}

alert("Here2 - showPopup is " + showPopup);

    if (showPopup){

        alert ("Still getting called" + showPopup);
for(let i=0;i<btns.length && showPopup;i++) {

        btns[i].onclick = function() {
        modals[i].style.display = "block";
        }

}

for(let i=0;i<spans.length && showPopup;i++){

        spans[i].onclick = function() {
        modals[i].style.display = "none";
        }

}
}}
```

I can get the `alert("Here - showPopup is " + showPopup);` to popup and then the return false cancels out the link, but the modal still show, please can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Inside the first `for` loop you are trying to set the global variable `showPopup` to false but, instead, you are declaring a new one.

Try replacing:

```
var showPopup = false;
```

by:

```
showPopup = false;
```